# Issue implementing the Command Processor pattern using MVVM for WPF?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, mvvm, wpf

I'm trying to implement the Command Processor pattern using MVVM for WPF. The Command Processor pattern that I'm roughly following is the one described in the book Pattern-Oriented Software Architecture (Volume 1):

> The Command Processor design pattern separates the request for a
> service from its execution. A command processor component manages
> requests as separate objects, schedules their execution, and provides
> additional services such as the storing of request objects for later
> undo.

My implementation requires that all possible UI actions that may be undoable be stored as commands. This is mostly compatible with WPF's Commands, except for TextBoxes. TextBoxes in WPF don't provide a Command (unlike Buttons and CheckBoxes).

I thought I solved this by adding a `TextChangedCommand` that executes when the `TextChanged` event is raised, like this:

```
<l:CommandTextBox
    Text="{Binding Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
    TextChangedCommand="{Binding SetNameCommand, Mode=OneWay}"
    />
```

But the problem is that the `TextChangedCommand` is executed not only when the user makes a change but whenever the data-bound property is changed, which happens when undoing the change. In an undo operation, I just want the property to be set to what it was previously, not run a command again.

It's like there needs to be a `TextChangedByUserCommand`, but before I try to implement this I'm wondering if I'm going about this the wrong way, or if someone has come up with a cleaner solution.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for this: [TextChange event of textbox is user initiated in wpf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23887570/textchange-event-of-textbox-is-user-initiated-in-wpf) ?

Comment: Something like that could work, thanks. It just means adding setter methods to every view model property, and remembering to call it instead of the property itself.